# How to determine if a NSWindow is tabbed or standalone?

Tags: tabs, nswindow, appkit, nswindowcontroller

In one of my `NSDocument` based apps the user can open a document detail in either a separate window or in a tab. Both windows are based on the same `NSWindowController` class and content view controller.

How can I determine from within the `NSWindowController` object if the `NSWindow` object is loaded as standalone window or as tab in the main document window?

All tab related properties of a `NSWindow` object as `tab`, `tabbedWindows` and `tabGroup` don't provide any useful info because they have the same values in both scenarios.

Comment: Do you mean `tab`, `tabbedWindows` and `tabGroup` aren't documented or don't return a useful value?

Comment: @Willeke Values of course. I have extended my question a bit.